# Amcharts 4 - Cursor does not match mouse position when screen is zoomed

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to implement an amchart4 chart on a screen that by css has a 95% zoom in the body (body zoom 95%).
I have verified that when this happens, the position of the mouse does not correspond to the position of the cursor. Do you know if there is any property or any other solution that can fix this gap?
This is the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/5kex32pa/1/
`Example of the code`

I saw the documentation but I didn't see nothing or I dont found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) is a non-standard feature. Replace it with `transform: scale(.95);` and it works. [Updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/k4qp7598/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Transform performs a complete rescaling of my entire website and their components and I only looking for a zoom of the web. With zoom, the components arent rescaling.

Comment: @developer can't you apply the transform only to `#chartdiv`?

Comment: Isn't possible because I have the zoom: 0.95 on body and I can't restore the zoom in the #chartdiv ( like another possibility )

Comment: @developer sorry but i'm not understanding. Why can't you remove the current zoom property from `body` and apply the transform to `#chartdiv`?

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: @developer does my updated example work as expected for you? If it does then you probably have other css properties which cause issues

Comment: I try to put `zoom: 1.10` in `#chartdiv` and its works. But I think its not the solution, I think its possible to fix with the amchats script.